# Can't add Bluetooth devices (Couldn't connect error)

Tags: windows, bluetooth, services

I recently installed a custom Windows iso (RekOs) but I can't get it to add Bluetooth devices. My Bluetooth drivers are up to date. My computer is discoverable on my phone, and I can connect to it from my phone. Bluetooth Support Service is running but I can't turn on Bluetooth Handsfree Service.